# Simple HTACCESS Issue for Membership Site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm a complete newbie.

I'm using Latest Wordpress 3.8.1

The issue is the login box(of private membership, located in /member_area) is appearing on home page .. which is just a landing page.. and I don't want this box to appear there.

I have a sub directory called member_area which is having all html files.. and in this sub-directory the following .htaccess is present:

```
########### AMEMBER START #####################
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Members Only"
AuthUserFile /home2/rtvouche/public_html/ph/amember/data/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /home2/rtvouche/public_html/ph/amember/data/.htgroup
Require  group  PRODUCT_1
########### AMEMBER FINISH ####################
```

Whereas in my root WP directory, the following .htaccess is present:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

So what I want is ... in only /member_area the login box should come... but it should not appear on homepage.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: is you member area also part of wordpress? the same wordpress that's running your "public" pages?

Comment: no, its not part of wordpress

Comment: Then you should put in a rewritecond to explicitly exempt your private subdirectory from the wordpress re-writing.

Comment: How? Since I'm a newbie.. I have no idea how to configure .htaccess

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks Marc for the wonderful pointer.

Answer (score 0):

For membership use plugin wp member this plugin used to arrage member